# Parallax эффект в CollapsingToolbarLayout - сплющивается картинка в заголовке

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar, parallax, toolbar

Пытаюсь [в несложном проекте на GitHub](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/tree/master/MyCoordinator) сделать заголовок с эффектом параллакса - как описано в блоге [Design Support Library: Collapsing Toolbar Layout](http://antonioleiva.com/collapsing-toolbar-layout/):

[image: app screenshot]

Но, к сожалению, картинку в заголовке "плющит":

[image: app 1]

[image: app 2]

В [activity_main.xml](https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/blob/q36/MyCoordinator/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_main.xml) я перепробовал различные комбинации **scaleType** (centerCrop и `fitCenter`) и **layoutHeight** (`match_parent` и `wrap_content`):

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/header2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
```

Помогите, пожалуйста, найти причину - почему мой заголовок работает не так, как с жирафом наверху.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне подсказали правильный ответ - я не заметил, что у меня в ImageView  картинка выставляется через `android:background` - и поэтому растягивается.

После смены на `android:src` все получилось:

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_image_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/header2"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />
```

[image: app screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

В примере по ссылке в этом месте

```
 <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
```

вместо вашего

> android:layout_height="200dp"

стоит

> android:layout_height="wrap_content"

Попробуйте сделать как в примере по вашей ссылке.

Comment: Попробовал, спасибо (+1) но теперь заголовок занял весь экран телефона

Comment: Попытался я себе ваш проект запустить, но очень уж он неудобно сделан. Если отдельным репозиторием выложите (чтоб его одним архивом слить) - я б даже посмотрел. Не собирать же мне его у себя по одному файлу.

Comment: На GitHub есть ссылка: https://github.com/afarber/android-newbie/archive/q36.zip и потом распаковать папку MyCoordinator

Comment: Эту ссылку я видел. Там 30Мб. А я сижу на острове посреди Северного Ледовитого, инет у нас через спутник и жёсткий лимит на трафик, коий стоит 10-ки тыщ казённых рублей в месяц. Качать 30Мб - не вариант совсем.

Comment: Я максимум метра 3 возьмусь качать, не больше)

Comment: Кароче у меня всё заработало сразу как я убрал всё лишнее и обновил все либы (включая саппорт, дизайн, ресайклер). Где и какие отличия от вашего кода - завтра поищу) Но на беглый взгляд - надо вам просто в ImageView высоту на android:layout_height="match_parent" выставить.